# dom element data attribute append if not exist

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am adding custom data attributes to div. Every time child is clicked it will add value to 'data-selected' attribute to parent (if not already exist), for example:

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child" title="a"></div>
     <div class="child" title="b"></div>
     <div class="child" title="something rather"></div>
     <div class="child" title="foo"></div>
</div>

var parent = $('.parent')

$(document).on('click', '.child', function(){
     var title = $(this).attr('title')

    //parent.attr('data-selected', title)
})
```

I know I can get parent attributes on child click, split them into array and compare values manually if already exist, but I am wondering is there a direct method which can do this?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you would find it *much* easier to use that library's `.data()` API to do this.

Comment: [jQuery `.data()` API](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: The *if not already exist* and *already* parts are unclear to me... Do you wish to store an array without duplicate value?